# Convert Objective C to Swift with error Type does not conform to protocal

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to convert the **objective c** code below to **swift**:

```
[MyClassListenersRegistry register__MyClassDataListener :[[MyClassMaintainer alloc] init]];
```

I'm getting the error

`"Type ‘MyClassMaintainer’ does not conform to protocol ‘MyClassListener' "`

when using **swift** code as below:

```
MyClassListenersRegistry.register__MyClassDataListener(MyClassMaintainer())
```

The objective c code is working but not swift. Am I converting correctly?

Please assist.

Comment: MyClassListenersRegistry.register__MyClassDataListener(MyClassMaintainer.self)

Comment: Hi, its doesn't seem to work...same error